# Why doesn't the list of modules at /admin/modules show module versions?

Tags: 9

I'm similarly investigating possible causes for `/admin/reports/updates` never showing any updates except for Drupal core and Zurb Foundation, nothing else is ever listed. `composer outdated "drupal/*"` shows a ton of available updates. This is Drupal 9.5.9.

Here's the composer file:

```
{
  "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
  "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
  "support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "woocommerce/flexslider",
        "version": "2.7.2",
        "type": "drupal-library",
        "extra": {
          "installer-name": "flexslider"
        },
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/archive/2.7.2.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "require": {
          "composer/installers": "~1.0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch",
        "version": "1.0",
        "type": "drupal-library",
        "extra": {
          "installer-name": "jquery-ui-touch-punch"
        },
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/archive/master.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "require": {
          "composer/installers": "~1.0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "jackmoore/colorbox",
        "version": "1.6.4",
        "type": "drupal-library",
        "extra": {
          "installer-name": "colorbox"
        },
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/archive/1.6.4.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        },
        "require": {
          "composer/installers": "~1.0"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
    "drupal-ckeditor-libraries-group/indentblock": "4.17.1",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.3",
    "drupal/audiofield": "^1.9",
    "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0@beta",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0",
    "drupal/calendar": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/ckeditor_entity_link": "^1.3",
    "drupal/ckeditor_indentblock": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/colorbox": "^2.0",
    "drupal/conditional_fields": "^4.0@alpha",
    "drupal/context": "^4.0@beta",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.0.0",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.0.0",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.0.0",
    "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9.0.0",
    "drupal/csv_serialization": "^2.0",
    "drupal/ctools": "^3.4",
    "drupal/date_popup": "^1.1",
    "drupal/devel": "^4.0",
    "drupal/devel_php": "^1.2",
    "drupal/draggableviews": "^2.0",
    "drupal/ds": "^3.9",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.1",
    "drupal/entity": "^1.1",
    "drupal/entityconnect": "^2.0@RC",
    "drupal/entityreference_filter": "^1.2",
    "drupal/field_delimiter": "^1.1",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
    "drupal/flexslider": "^2.0",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
    "drupal/imce": "^2.2",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.1",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_checkboxradio": "^2.0",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_datepicker": "^2.0",
    "drupal/jquery_ui_tabs": "^1.1",
    "drupal/masonry": "^1.1",
    "drupal/masonry_views": "^1.1",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.3",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.12",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
    "drupal/quicktabs": "^3.0@alpha",
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.29",
    "drupal/token": "^1.7",
    "drupal/upgrade_status": "^3.0",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
    "drupal/views_bulk_operations": "^3.9",
    "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.0",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^1.7",
    "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
    "drupal/zurb_foundation": "^6.0",
    "drush/drush": "^10",
    "furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch": "~1.0",
    "jackmoore/colorbox": "~1.0",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2.0",
    "woocommerce/flexslider": "~2.0"
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "preferred-install": "source",
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true,
      "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
      "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
      "drupal/core-project-message": true,
      "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true,
      "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
      }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
      "web/core": [
        "type:drupal-core"
      ],
      "web/libraries/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-library"
      ],
      "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-module"
      ],
      "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-profile"
      ],
      "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-theme"
      ],
      "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-drush"
      ],
      "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-custom-module"
      ],
      "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-custom-profile"
      ],
      "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
        "type:drupal-custom-theme"
      ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
      "include-keys": [
        "homepage",
        "support"
      ],
      "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
        "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
        "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
        "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
        "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
        "",
        "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
        "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
        "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
        "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
        "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
        "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
        "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
      ]
    },
    "patches": {
      "drupal/core": {
        "#2457999: Cannot use relationship for rendered entity on Views": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-12-01/cannot-use-relationship-2457999-259.patch"
      }
    },
    "merge-plugin": {
      "include": [
        "web/modules/contrib/masonry/composer.libraries.json"
      ]
    }
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "drupal/twig_xdebug": "^1.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: They are probably installed from Git checkouts rather than packaged releases. This question is impossible to answer factually minus the full composer.json file.

Comment: @cilefen I've edited the post to include it.

Comment: It is exactly what I thought it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is:

```
"preferred-install": "source"
```

To get packaged projects including the Drupal version string set, you must use:

```
"preferred-install": "dist"
```

Comment: Brilliant, good catch. I'll need to check the history of the file to make sure there isn't a legitimate reason for that. That's probably also the reason that I'm not getting update status.